# Disabling X server on Fedora 17

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, startup

How can I prevent the X server from starting up on Fedora 17? In older versions the user should edit `/etc/inittab` but in this version (I didn't check this on previous versions) Fedora uses some other mechanisms to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the manual [online](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd#How_do_I_change_the_default_runlevel.3F):

> systemd uses symlinks to point to the default runlevel. You have to delete the existing symlink first before creating a new one

So...

```
rm /etc/systemd/system/default.target
ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

To switch back:

```
rm /etc/systemd/system/default.target
ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target
```

You will still get the graphical boot splash. To remove the boot splash, remove "rhgb" from /etc/default/grub...

```
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.md=0 rd.lvm=0 rd.dm=0 SYSFONT=True  KEYTABLE=us rd.luks=0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rhbg quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.md=0 rd.lvm=0 rd.dm=0 SYSFONT=True  KEYTABLE=us rd.luks=0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 quiet"
```

and then run grub2-mkconfig...

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

To solve the missing "True" font [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=799401):

Change every occurrence of the word, True, with latarcyrheb-sun16 or latarcyrheb-sun32 in these files:

```
/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
/etc/sysconfig/i18n
/etc/default/grub
```

and then run grub2-mkconfig...

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Comment: I applied all of the above but nothing happened and Fedora start graphically.

Comment: YES! I do it again and it worked. First time I entered grub2-mkconfig without `-o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`.

Comment: On a side note, Fedora 19 broke/improved `startx`. Instead of `startx -- :1`, do `startx -- vt1` where `vt1` is a virtual terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Fedora uses systemd for [maintaining runlevels](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd)

```
# rm /etc/systemd/system/default.target 
# ln -sf /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target /etc/systemd/system/default.target
```